# Excel VBA to login in through a Excel-add-in using username and password

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, add-in

I have an Add-in installed within excel. Everytime I open up the Excel such login will pop up a window and ask for a user name and password in order to use the add in function. I know Excel VBA could login in Gmail given UserName and Password. Wondering if Excel VBA is capable of logingging such ADD IN automatically without myself typing in the users and password every single time.

Thanks in advance. Any hints will be greatly appreciated!
I need to automatically open this spreadsheet and login the addin in order to do some update in the background.

Comment: Hmmmm the popup/form is likely part of the Add-Ins executable code, because that code is running, there is not going to be a way to use Excel VBA in the same instance of Excel to control it. There *may* be a way you can do this using WinAPI and the windows handle of the form (although I'm not sure if UF's have a "handle") but you'd probably have to use a separate instance of Excel to do it.

Comment: Can I use python open the Excel, and use python to handle this add-in pop up login. I sort of understand you cant use code on another code instance level within Excel. Any further direction or suggestion where I should go. Thx so much :)

Comment: You could maybe do that but I wouldn't be able to tell you how.  I think similarly though you would have to use python to get the Hwnd of the userfirm if possible. If you can do that with WinAPI then it's probably possible

Comment: Hi David, Still bit lost. Can I use WinAPI in this case then?

Comment: I don't know if you can,  nor if you need to or if it can be done another way.  I've taken some very intro course in python but have not used it prifessionally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacky way, try some legitimate auto-type tools to if helps:
http://help.agilebits.com/1Password_Windows/auto-type.html
http://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html